# ImportError: No module named adafruit_motor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adafruit

I just installed the Adafruit MotorKit library and I created a little bit of code like this:

```
from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit
kit = MotorKit()
```

But when I start the program with sudo command : sudo python motortest.py I had this :

ImportError: No Module named adafruit_motorkit

I do not understand because I followed the installation procedure of the library with the command: sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-motorkit

I run my program from raspbian desktop on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you install the module via `pip3` so you need to run the script with `python3` .

like this: `sudo python3 motortest.py`

Comment: you shouldn't run python scripts as sudo - you'll get this error because the instruction say to install it with sudo pip3 - if you just run pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-motorkit OP can run the script without sudo